# How is Retrofit 2 processing the functions annotations from the API service interface passed to retrofit.create()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new to programming in Java and try to understand how annotations works in big libraries.

Can someone show me code snippet in which retrofit is actually processing the functions annotations from the API service interface that I pass as the argument to retrofit.create method and change its behavior based on this? I mean: @GET, @POST etc

I created the interface Giphy Api Service with next function:

```kotlin
@GET("gifs/search")
    fun getSearchedGifs(
        @Query("q") searchTerm: String,
        @Query("limit") limit: Int = 50,
        @Query("offset") offset: Int = 0,
        @Query("rating") rating: String = "g",
        @Query("lang") lang: String = "en",
        @Query("bundle") bundle: String = "messaging_non_clips",
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = "my api key"
    ): Call<DataResult>
```

this function have @GET("gifs/search") which represent the HTTP GET request.

Then I use this interface to create instance of retrofit object in the next code:

```kotlin
val retroService = retrofit.create(GiphyApiService::class.java)
```

I checked retrofit.create() method and all file, but do not find answer to my question

Comment: Annotations generates code for you. We programmers are lazy by default and always find way to create thing quickly. You annotate your method with predefined  annotations which compiler can understand and generate code for us. Try learning before retrofit how Android api call was made using http client.

Comment: I understand it at a high level of abstract but I want to go deeper. I tried to find where is actually programmed "code generation" for us.

Thanks I will try to google how how Android api calls was made using http client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit2 uses a [dynamic proxy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies) to make an interface implementation instead of the code generation.
It parses your methods with the refletion, makes `SeriveMethod` of methods and caches them into `serviceMethodCache`.

When you invoke a method of your interface, a created `ServiceMethod` will be invoked instead.